# Kibana-Elasticsearch stack: QueryParsingException

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Querying elasticsearch through kibana works as expected but any use of `Add filter to match this value` or `Add filter to NOT match this value` fails:

[image: Clicking on these buttons throws an exception]

The exception thrown by elasticsearch is-

`QueryParsingException[[logstash-2014.02.24] No query registered for [field]]`

[image]

Kibana's config.js points at my elasticsearch server and the nginx forward includes the port 9200 and ES is reachable from the client end (all graphs load all right).

`elasticsearch: "https://es.cloudexample.com",`

The log at elasticsearch end is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qY4eA7UW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Kibana and Elasticsearch are you targeting? I had a similar problem today after upgrading to Elasticsearch 1.0 on Friday, thought Kibana was still working fine (page loaded and the graphs + data still displayed) until I tried adding a filter at which point it started spitting out error messages.

I upgraded Kibana to version 3 milestone 5 (the current latest version) and the problem went away.

Comment: Thank you so much Will. :)
So kibana3milestone4 works well with elasticsearch 0.9 but breaks in this particular case and as you indicated, kibana3milestone4 gels well with es 1.0.